# Browser executes most, but not all of my php

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could give me a hand. My browser is executing most of my php code, but when it gets to certain line, it prints the code instead of executing it.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php


//Display registration form

function register_form(){


$date = date('D, M, Y');

echo <form action='?act=register' method='post'>

Username: <input type='text' name='username' size='30'><br>

Password: <input type='password' name='password' size='30'><br>

Confirm your password: <input type='password' name='password_conf' size='30'><br>

Email: <input type='text' name='email' size='30'><br>

<input type='hidden' name='date' value='$date'>

<input type='submit' value='Register'>

</form>;


}
?>

<?php


//Register users data.

function register(){


//Connecting to database

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username" "password");

if(!$connect){

die(mysql_error());

}


//Selecting database

$select_db = mysql_select_db("database", $connect);

if(!$select_db){

die(mysql_error());

}
?>

<?php


//Collecting info

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];

$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$pass_conf = $_REQUEST['password_conf'];

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$date = $_REQUEST['date'];


//Check input fields


if(!empty($username)){

die("Please enter your username!<br>");

}

if(!empty($password)){

die('Please enter your password!<br>');

}

if(!empty($pass_conf)){

die("Please confirm your password!<br>");

}

if(!empty($email)){

die("Please enter your email!");

}
?>

<?php


//Check username availability


$user_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

$do_user_check = mysql_num_rows($user_check);

//Check if email availability


$email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

$do_email_check = mysql_num_rows($email_check);

//Display errors


if($do_user_check > 0){

die("Username is already in use!<br>");

}

if($do_email_check > 0){

die("Email is already in use!");

}

//Check if passwords match


if($password != $pass_conf){

die("Passwords don't match!");

}

?>

<?php

//Register user


$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");

if(!$insert){

die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());

}


echo $username.", you are now registered. Thank you!<br><a href=login.php>Login</a>" ;


}
?>

<?php

switch($act){


default;

register_form();

break;


case "register";

register();

break;


}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

It prints a lot of the closing ?> tags, but if I remove the tag as well as its opening counterpart, it prints all the code that was between. I've been stuck on this for the last few days and really need some help. Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE*** 
I figured it out. I was executing from the directory instead of the address. (not sure if I worded that right). So instead browser pointing to registration page from "http://localhost:port/register.php" it was pointing to "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/register.php"

Comment: Where is qoutes for `echo`? Should be `echo "some string here"`

Comment: It's not your browser that executes `php`. `php` is a server side language. With that said, how is this code executing at all? You have syntax errors. Would also help to specify which lines you're encountering problems on.

Comment: So where are we with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Put double quotes around anything you to be `echoed` since there are single quotes used inside the strings. A simple example:

Ps. you have some other syntax errors as well, but if *only* you care.

One of them on line 45: `$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username" "password");` this is definitely not  the way it should be. Even if it was;

> Notice the missing `comma` after `"username".  Should have been like:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
```

For the current problem, try this:

```
<?php


//Display registration form

function register_form(){


$date = date('D, M, Y');

echo "<form action='?act=register' method='post'>

Username: <input type='text' name='username' size='30'><br>

Password: <input type='password' name='password' size='30'><br>

Confirm your password: <input type='password' name='password_conf' size='30'><br>

Email: <input type='text' name='email' size='30'><br>

<input type='hidden' name='date' value='$date'>

<input type='submit' value='Register'>

</form>;";


}
?>
```

Comment: So I added the double quotes. That fixed some of the code displaying on the browser, now this keeps displaying `"; } ?> "); } if(!empty($password)){ die('Please enter your password!
'); } if(!empty($pass_conf)){ die("Please confirm your password!
"); } if(!empty($email)){ die("Please enter your email!"); } ?> 0){ die("Username is already in use!
"); } if($do_email_check > 0){ die("Email is already in use!"); } //Now let's check does passwords match if($password != $pass_conf){ die("Passwords don't match!"); } ?> Login" ; } ?>`

Comment: Also, can you please explain what you meant about line 45 not being the way it should be?

Comment: @Madness can you please tell me what did you mean by _this keeps displaying_? Is it the code that you've written in the comment? If so kindly edit your question with your exact approach of writing the code so we can understand what you're trying to do. Also on the side note, please start off with either mysqli or PDO even if it is for practicing purposes. I am here to clear any further doubts/problems for as much as I can. Cheers

Comment: I guess i would say instead of executing the code above, the server prints it on the browser after the form is displayed. So instead of just the form being visible, it's the form plus the printed code right next to it.

Comment: @Madness that clearly means you were not running it on _localhost_ Kindly check your url and make sure you were running on localhost and not a directory likefile:///C:/xampp

Answer (score 0):

You need to put double quotes around your echoed strings. (double, since you use single quotes inside your tags). If you remove the php-tags, it will be interpreted as just HTML i.e. it will just be sent out to the browser. 
If for some reason you hate quotes, you might like to do it as a here document:

```
echo <<<EOF
<form action='?act=register' method='post'>

Username: <input type='text' name='username' size='30'><br>
...
EOF
```

There's also at least one missing comma in you code, which will keep that part from executing (in `mysql_connect`). 
B.t.w. you shouldn't use the mysql_*-type functions anymore. They are marked deprecated and are prone to make your code succeptible to SQL injection attacks. I recommend working into PDOs.

And just for wiw, as someone already mentioned in the comments it is not the browser that executes this code. PHP is interpreted by the webserver. The only scripting language that is actually executed browserside is still javascript (correct me if I'm wrong.).

Comment: Wasn't planning on implementing this, this is purely for me practicing some PHP and mysql. Thanks for the heads up though.